# Правильно ли так говорить?

Tags: управление

У Куприна: Ромашов насторожился и, глядя не на Петерсона, а на председателя, ответил грубовато: "Да, бывал, но я не понимаю, какое **это отношение имеет к делу**".

'это отношение имеет к делу' - разве так говорят? По-моему, нужно так: 'какое это имеет отношение к делу'

Comment: ну вы хоть в цитатах, в выделенном вами тексте ошибки-то проверяйте.

Comment: @behemothus, это опечатка, исправить после её нельзя самому

Comment: Это почему это нельзя? Свой текст вы всегда можете править на общих основаниях.  Ну как скажете.

Answer (score 4):

Как мне кажется, нормальный порядок слов такой: **"Да, бывал, но я не понимаю, какое отношение это  имеет к делу".**

Скорее всего, здесь имеет место **инверсия** — нарушение обычного порядка слов в предложении.

"В литературе инверсия - стилистический прием, при котором используется нестандартный порядок слов, придающий предложению красивое звучание и особый смысл.  С его помощью писатель может сделать акцент на каком-либо действии или слове...

...Подведем итог, перечислив достоинства инверсии: инверсия позволяет сделать акцент на определенном слове или словосочетании; расставляет в предложении смысловые нагрузки; в поэтическом тексте инверсия задает ритм; **в прозе с помощью инверсии можно расставить логические ударения**; инверсия передает отношение автора к героям и эмоциональное состояние автора; инверсия оживляет текст и делает его более читабельным и интересным".

[Что такое инверсия? | Elhow](http://elhow.ru/ucheba/literatura/literaturnye-ponjatija/chto-takoe-inversija)

В приведенном примере инверсия, действительно,  **выделяет смысловой центр высказывания и передает эмоциональное состояние героя.**